# How can we generate flow chart diagram in IntelliJ IDEA from Java code which is editable?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, flowchart

I am searching for a tool (preferably works offline) but couldn't find any.how  can generate flow chart. i.e flow chart for a method or for the main method of the class.

I am aware of Sequence diagrams and its plugin for IntelliJ. but I am looking searching for a tool which generates flow charts instead of the sequence.

Comment: Has anyone found any tools yet?. There is one lucrative tool named as findtheflow but I cannot make it work either in standalone mode or intellij.

Answer (score 12):

You can try the SequenceDiagram for IntelliJ IDEA plugin.
 It generates simple sequence diagrams which are a visible representation of code flows (via the method calls).

As for flow charts specifically (unfortunately I did not find an IntelliJ solution):
You can try the online code2flow which is a simple `paste code and edit the generated chart' solution. Obviously, it is not a part of IntelliJ but it will get the job done.
Another option is the FateSoft application, which generates flow charts for multiple programming languages. Simply install the tool on your workstation and parse the desired code in the app, while selecting the start and end line of code from which to generate the flow chart.

References:

- [SequenceDiagram plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8286-sequencediagram)
- [Usage guide of the SequenceDiagram plugin](https://blog.voidmainvoid.net/49)
- [Code2flow online flow chart generator](https://code2flow.com/app)
- [FateSoft flow chart generator](http://www.fatesoft.com/s2f/)

Comment: thank you. but I am searching for a tool which generates a flow chart.

Answer (score 0):

start
Declarations
string carType
num days
num STANDARD = 65
num COMPACT = 40
num SUB = 30
num DISCOUNT = 0.2
num DAYSDISCOUNT = 7
string QUIT = “ZZZ”
num rate
num discount

```
output “Please enter the car type that you would like to rent or,”, QUIT, “ to exit”  
input carType  

while carType <> QUIT   
    output “Please enter number of days you would like to rent the car”   
    input days   
    
    if carType == “Standard” then    
        rate = STANDARD   
    else    
        if carType == “Compact” then     
            rate = COMPACT    
        else      
            if carType == “subcompact” then      
                rate = SUB     
            else       
                rate = 0      
                output “Invalid car type”     
            endif    
        endif   
    endif 
    
    if rate <> 0 then 
        if days >= DAYSDISCOUNT then 
            discount = rate * DISCOUNT 
            rate = rate – discount 
        endif 
    endif 
    
    output rate  
    output “Please enter the car type that you would like to rent or,”, QUIT, “ to exit the program” 
    input carType 
endwhile 

stop
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).